# What's happening to my Marigold plant?

Tags: leaves, diseases, discoloration, marigold

I sowed seeds for Marigold (purchased from Home Depot) and used Miracle Pro potting mix. The seeds germinated quickly and my plant grew 6-8 inches. From past 10 days, I am seeing the peripheral leaves turning purple-brown. I have no idea what's causing this. I water them daily, they are in full sun (like a marigold needs) and the pot is well drained. I would be so grateful if you guys can help me out. I can see a white powdery thing on the surface of the soil in one of my marigold (I have total two). I feel its some sort of fungus infection but I am not sure. I read online that phosphorous deficiency can also cause the leaves to turn purple. The discoloration is not spotted. The entire leaf is turning purple-brown.
Please help me and my plants.

Thanks,
Raina

Comment: Marigolds are pretty care free. My guess is overwatering.

Comment: Please add some photos.

Comment: Photos please and where are you in the world?